# FirebaseX doesn't have firebaseInstanceId

Tags: typescript, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging, cordova-plugins, ionic4

I have backend API like so:

```
      registerFcmToken(userIdToken: string, firebaseInstanceId: string, fcmToken: 
string): Promise<ConfirmationResponseModel> {
        // code
      }
```

Can you tell me what should I send here? `firebaseInstanceId`

I use FirebaseX plugin here: https://github.com/dpa99c/cordova-plugin-firebasex#api

I can generate  `this.fcmToken = await this.firebase.getToken();` But what is `firebaseInstanceId`?

Firebase doc says this: https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/iid/FirebaseInstanceId.html#public-taskinstanceidresult-getinstanceid-

But what is the equivalent of FirebaseX?

Comment: It might help if you edit the question explain what you're trying to achieve here.  With the question right now, we're left guessing why you ever need something called `firebaseInstanceId` and what it can do for your backend method that shows no code.

Comment: @DougStevenson I'll pass your message to my backend dev and let you know if I'll get any message from him. Above has a frontend code. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If you check the code, you can see that there is a method called `getId()` :

https://github.com/dpa99c/cordova-plugin-firebasex/blob/master/www/firebase.js#L14

```
exports.getId = function (success, error) {
  exec(success, error, "FirebasePlugin", "getId", []);
};
```

This method is calling the method `getId()` in the java class `FirebasePlugin`:

```
     private void getId(final CallbackContext callbackContext) {
        cordova.getThreadPool().execute(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    String id = FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getId();
                    callbackContext.success(id);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    handleExceptionWithContext(e, callbackContext);
                }
            }
        });
    }
```

https://github.com/dpa99c/cordova-plugin-firebasex/blob/master/src/android/FirebasePlugin.java#L392

So basically `this.firebase.getId()` should give you the instance id

Comment: The problem here is this doesn't have such a method too?  https://github.com/dpa99c/cordova-plugin-firebasex#api

Comment: The links are from the same Github repository https://github.com/dpa99c/cordova-plugin-firebasex/blob/master/www/firebase.js#L14

Comment: Also not sure which firebase version this plugin uses but the method `getToken()` that is being used is deprecated https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/iid/FirebaseInstanceId.html#public-string-gettoken-

Comment: `this.firebase.getId();` says `Property 'getId' does not exist on type 'FirebaseX'.` Why?

Comment: This is the version: `"firebase": "7.4.0",`

Comment: The problem here is Ionic native wrapper. No such method there: https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic-native/blob/master/src/%40ionic-native/plugins/firebase-x/index.ts

Comment: @Sampath if you want to send a notification, all you need is the fcm token https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/firebase-x, its also explained here https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/first-message#retrieve-the-current-registration-token `String token = task.getResult().getToken();` is the instance id token that you use to send notification